# App name showing incorrectly on the ticker

Tags: facebook, http, url, https, ticker

We have an old name for the app and we want the app to show the correct name on the ticker but we have not been able to do it (it is still showing the old name). We updated the title of the url canvas and submitted it on the debugger and interestingly enough, the title is taken correctly on the https address  (it is shown on the debugger page but not in the ticker) but not on the http url. Actually it says for the http that the app has problems with the meta tags.  Any idea on how to fix this problem? Thanks a Lot, Gilmer

Comment: Did you fix the issues with the meta tags? As far as I know, unless the crawler gets a good set of tags, it won't update the cache so your app name will still use the old value

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Enter your url in that and try to generate all the information.
If that is not showing any errors in that, then scroll down at the end of the page.
You will find block named as "URLs"

Click on the first link named as: "Graph API:".

This will solve your issue.

In future, if you are going to change any content from your page, then don't forget to do the same process once again.

Thanks!